# Group permissions when running a program with the SETUID bit

Tags: linux, permissions, setuid

I'm setting up a system where users can via SFTP upload png files which will be later copied to a directory accessible from the www server, one file after each few hours. The only thing left to do is to set up the permissions correctly and I failed to do that.

The server is a Cubieboard and the OS is Cubian (port of Debian)

Let's say I have two users, "testaftertime" and "testaftertime2". They get their directories. "/eizm/data/aftertime/testaftertime" which belongs to user "testaftertime" and group "testaftertime". Similarly for the other user.

The users should have access to their directories but others should not. That's why th owner has "rwx" rights, and the others have "---". But the directories should also be accessible by a bot (which copies the png files and reads or changes configuration files). The bot is run by the user "b". The user "b" is added to the groups "testaftertime" and "testaftertime2". And the group permission for those directories is "rwx". So the bot can access those directories without problems.

On the www server, there is also a viewer. Which should allow to view the pictures that were already copied from those directories. But the viewer should be able to access the configuration files inside the directories. If someone enters the URL "/aftertime/viewer?story=testaftertime" the server will call the program "/eizm/pro/aftertime/viewer".
The server is run by the user "www-data" and the user "www-data" should not be added to the groups "testaftertime" and "testaftertime2" because these directories should not be normally accessible from the www server.
The program "/eizm/pro/aftertime/viewer" belongs to the user "b" and has the SETUID bit set. So the viewer program even when called from the server has all the permissions of the user "b" (I did this in other cases when a CGI program had to access a file or directory which belongs to the user "b") and because the user "b" belongs to the group "testaftertime", the viewer shouldn't have problems accessing the directory "/eizm/data/aftertime/testaftertime".

But it doesn't work. The viewer does not get access to those directories (but has no problems accessing directories that belong to "b" and only "b" can read them). It looks like when running the program with the SETUID bit, the fact that user "b" belongs to the groups is not recognized.

Can this be changed?

Or is there an other way of setting up the system so that:

1.the users can access their own directories, but not the directories of each other.

2.the user "b" has access to all those directories (without becoming root).

3.the program "/eizm/pro/aftertime/viewer" has access to all those directories regardless of which user calls the program (without becoming root).
?

Comment: I believe this question makes more sense on [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Just a hint, If you end up having 5 paragraphs of boring black text, and nothing more, you probably failed to phrase the question. Take me, I'll not read all that text.